# Upgrading mobo, cpu and memory - will a host OS still work as a guest in a Hyper-V VM?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008

I will be migrating my Windows 7 install to a VHD to use inside Windows Server 2008 Hyper V, but I plan on upgrading my memory, CPU and mobo. Once these hardware upgrades are done, this is when I will then install Windows Server as the host OS.

Is it possible that the Windows 7 VHD will still work even on the new hardware, as a Hyper-V VM?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, converting a physical machine to .vhd usually requires re-activation.

However, using [VMware vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) results in a VM that doesn't require activation.
I have no idea what VMware does that achieves this miracle.

If you must have the VM in .vhd format, maybe you should try [VMDK to VHD Converter](http://vmtoolkit.com/blogs/announcements/archive/2006/11/20/vmdk-to-vhd-converter-available.aspx) (which I never tried). If the VMware file is over 2GB, you should first read this article: [How to convert a (big) VMWare VMDK into an Hyper-V VHD](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2008/10/16/How-to-convert-a-big-VMWare-VMDK-into-an-Hyper-V-VHD.aspx). Another reference is [VMware to Hyper-V migration easier than expected](http://www.aaronpalermo.com/wordpress/archives/32).

Answer (score 0):

It will work. As far as virtual machine is concerned, only processor type will change. Everything else is anyhow emulated.

Activation will happen if two things are changed (e.g. processor and memory). As long as you keep configuration of your virtual machine same as before, Windows will not require reactivation.

Comment: +1 ... but IF memory is 'anyhow emulated', then THIS would be an option too :) http://downloadmoreram.net/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however you may possibly run into issues with Windows 7 thinking its been installed on a different PC (activation issues).  The processor type will change, and that could render some of the architecture-specific functions that Windows 7 uses inoperable.  I would recommend staying with the same line of CPU unless you don't mind a reformat.

Comment: This is what I was wondering too (activation).

Comment: That would be my biggest concern.  I've done this personally with Windows XP and ran into problems with activation.